# Configuring process.env object with a Nodejs script

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, dotenv

Is it possible to add an environment variable using a Nodejs CLI script to the process.env object and have it available in a javascript environment?

Something like this

```
node index.js --env --NEW_VARIABLE=1
```

```
// index.js

console.log('process.env["NEW_VARIABLE"]:', process.env["NEW_VARIABLE"]);
// logs 1
```

If it is, can it be done with strings, and how?
One more thing, assuming all of this can be done...can it be done with a Jest script as well?

Comment: You could have your nodejs script process command line arguments and set things in the environment from that.  You could set the actual environment variables from your command script before running nodejs and nodejs would inherit them.  Otherwise, the [dotenv module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) is often used for a similar purpose.

Comment: see [`cross-env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) module

Comment: Thanks for your responses, I've found something that works. There's another property on the process object called "argv" which is an array of strings. You can push arguments into this array via a script. src: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-command-line-arguments-node-scripts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's another property on the process object called "argv". It's an array of strings. You can push arguments into the argv array by added them as flags at the end of a CLI script.

ex:

```
node index.js -"new variable"
```

```
// index.js

console.log('process.argv:', process.argv);

/*
process.argv: [
      '/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/bin/node',
      '/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/bin/jest',
      '__tests__/api.test.js',
      '-new variable' // <- 
    ]
*/
```

This will work with both node and jest scripts

source: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-command-line-arguments-node-scripts